# C#、Unityでエラー（CS0246）が出てしまう

Tags: c#, unity3d

Unityで[YouTubeのチュートリアル動画](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEGCoV_X7Io&list=PLZ1b66Z1KFKgkE9ji0tF2iDO0LGxmlwIm&index=5)を見ながらゲームを作っていますが、
この動画の15分49秒のプログラムがこちらの実行ですとエラーを起こします。

具体的なエラーメッセージは以下の通りです。

```
Assets/Scripts/LapTimeManager.cs(22,31): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'text' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

同様のようなエラーが残り4つほど検出されます。
よろしくおねがいします。

**ソースコード:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class LapTimeManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static int MinuteCount;
    public static int SecondCount;
    public static float MilliCount;
    public static string MilliDisplay;

    public GameObject MinuteBox;
    public GameObject SecondBox;
    public GameObject MilliBox;


    void Update()
    {
        MilliCount += Time.deltaTime * 10;
        MilliDisplay = MilliCount.ToString("F0");
        MilliBox.GetComponent<text> ().text = "" + MilliDisplay;

        if(MilliCount >= 10)
        {
            MilliCount = 0;
            SecondCount += 1;
        }

        if(SecondCount <= 9)
        {
            SecondBox.GetComponent<text> ().text = "0" + SecondCount + ".";
        } else
        {
            SecondBox.GetComponent<text> ().text = "" + SecondCount + ".";
        }

        if(SecondCount >= 60)
        {
            SecondCount = 0;
            MinuteCount += 1;
        }

        if (SecondCount <= 9)
        {
            SecondBox.GetComponent<text> ().text = "0" + SecondCount + ".";
        }
        else
        {
            SecondBox.GetComponent<text> ().text = "" + SecondCount + ".";
        }


    　　　}　
　　　}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetComponent`はメソッドの名前で、その後に続く`<Text>`は「Text型で呼ぶ」というジェネリックメソッドの型パラメーターです。

今回、その型の部分に誤って小文字の`text`を書いてしまっており、「text型が見つからない」というエラーになっています。

C#では大文字小文字を区別しますので気をつけましょう。

```
MilliBox.GetComponent<Text> ().text = "" + MilliDisplay;
```